# How to correct this query in java such it access the variable SequenceId and gets the value of the sequence from database

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I have an error stating that"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

```
 rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde t where t.ACTION = 804 and t.seq > ? order by t.seq desc" + sequenceID);
```

Comment: What value does `sequnceID` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde t where t.ACTION = 804 and t.seq > " + sequenceID + " order by t.seq desc");
```

Comment: (potentially) Open to SQL Injection.  Please set a good example by showing parameterized queries where possible.

Answer (score 2):

you are concatenating `sequenceID` to you query. its not a valid query.

I think your query should be something like below:

```
     rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde t 
      where t.ACTION = 804 and t.seq > ? order by t.seq desc");  
     PreparedStatement.setInt(1,sequenceID );// setting the column using preparedStatement
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass sequenceID as parameter to the prepared-statement.

```
  String query="select * from msg_new_to_bde t where t.ACTION = 804 and t.seq > ? order by t.seq desc"; 
  // int(your datatype) input parameterized.  
  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);  
  st.setInt(1, sequenceID);  
  rs = st.executeQuery();
```